# How to store lower or higher values from AVX/AVX2(YMM) register to memory like the SSE movlps/movhps does?

Tags: x86, sse, simd, avx, avx2

Is there any existing instructions which could store lower or higher values from a 256 bit AVX/AVX2(YMM) register to memory address, just like the SSE instruction movlps/movhps does?

Or is there any other way to implement this?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You could use the [insert/extract instructions](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/stdxe/2013/composerxe/compiler/cpp-mac/GUID-290F279F-1BC4-4A46-858A-10D41F58B81F.htm). Those will pull them into another register. So you'll still need a separate load/store instruction. But that said, it isn't any different than just using a 128-bit permute to swap the two halves.

Comment: Thanks @Mysticial! I found AVX2 vextractf128 may work for this.

Answer (score 7):

Store the low128 with `vmovdqu [rdi], xmm0`.

Store the high128 with `VEXTRACTI128 xmm1/m128, ymm2, 1`.  Probably you can get a compiler to generate a store to memory by assigning the result of an extract intrinsic to a memory reference.

`vextracti128 / f128` takes 2 uops, even in the fused domain (Haswell), so IDK what the point of having it encodable with an immediate operand of 0 is.  (until AVX512, when an immediate index instead of a `movh` becomes relevant, since they didn't know they were going to replace VEX with EVEX for AVX512).  There's no penalty for mixing AVX2 with xmm regs and AVX2 with ymm regs, so you can just use a 128b store of the xmm version to get the low 128, just like you can get the low32 of a 64b GP reg by referencing `eax` instead of `rax`.

It's probably annoying to cast stuff when using intrinsics, so with luck a compiler will compile `_mm256_extracti128_si256 (vec, 0)` to a `vmovdqu` of the corresponding xmm reg.  But if your compiler doesn't, your code will be faster if you get it to generate `vmovdqu`.  (`movdqu` is as fast as `vmovdqa` if the address is aligned, just like non-mov AVX memory access.)

Comment: One another solution is `vmovaps XMMWORD PTR [rdi], xmm0` for the lower 128 part. GCC/clang compile `_mm_store_ps(ptr, _mm256_castps256_ps128(v))` to that for Haswell and above.

Comment: @plasmacel: No CPUs have bypass-delay penalties for stores, so `movups` / `movaps` save a byte of machine code in the legacy SSE (non-VEX) encoding.  There's no point favouring `vmovaps` over `vmovdqa`, though, but also no downside so I guess it makes gcc's code simpler to always use `...ps` stores.